# sql dynamic replacement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My requirement is that I am searching a bunch of columns in a table using regex_like function: Below is an example:

```
SELECT *
FROM dsopi_person_addr_rule ADDR
WHERE regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line1),   
                     'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
```

Now what I would like to do if I find a match I would like to take the value from src_address_line1 and put that in another column of of the same table. I know how to do this but can anyone recommend how to do this efficiently. I am open to using cursors.

Comment: I don't understand why this has the SQL tag. I got flamed the other day for asking MS SQL specific syntax with the SQL tag.. I think that this should be clarified somehow. I don't think that you should flag 'SQL' here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need cursor for this

```
UPDATE dsopi_person_addr_rule ADDR
SET new_col = addr.src_address_line1
WHERE regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line1),   
                     'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
```

Comment: I guess sometimes we make even the most simplest solution complicated lol... Thanks for this!

Answer (score -1):

I'd take a look at the CONTAINSTABLE clause, but that would require enabling / creating FULLTEXT indexes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx

Comment: why are you posting T-sql SQL server answers for Oracle based questions

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the ORACLE tag.